# AutoHotKey home/end simulation

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to simulate the functionality of the home button (go to the begging of the line) using the keys: ctrl+left (like cmd+left in Mac OS) but for some reason its taking me to the beginning of the document.

Similarly, ctrl+right takes me to the end of the document where I want it to go to the end of the line.So, what am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
^left::Home
^right::End
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because Ctrl is still being held down from user when you press ctrl+left and windows interprets that as ctrl+home.

Adding

```
Send,{ctrl up}
```

before

```
Send, {Home}
```

will send out only Home, because Ctrl will be up(not pressed) for a moment.

Don't forget to use proper style when writing multi-line hotkey code.

```
hotkey::
    code
    code
return
```

Comment: Any idea why ^+left::Send,{Shift}{Home} wont work? (Trying to highlight the text till the beginning of the line)

Comment: @mixkat {Shift down} instead of {Shift}

Answer (score 5):

Actually, as soon as you use `Send`, the modifiers (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in this case) are ignored anyway, so the `Send,{ctrl up}` is superfluous,  but doesn't hurt either.

It can be reduced to two one-liners like this:

```
^Left::Send, {Home}
^Right::Send, {End}
```